# Join integers to a comma seperated string the pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I often do things like that:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> s = ''
>>> for i in x:
...  s = '{}, {}'.format(s, i)
... 
>>> s
', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
>>> if s[0] == ',':
...  s = s[2:]
... 
>>> s
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
```

I often think that there is a more pythonic-3 way to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str` has a [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) built-in to handle this:

```
', '.join(str(_) for _ in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
res = ', '.join(map(str, res))
```

Comment: Looks _interesting_. Can you use the object names of my example and explain a little bit. I don't understand that code. e.g. why do you use the class name `str` as a parameter for `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.join`:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = ', '.join(str(i) for i in x)
```

`str` is used because `join` can only connect elements that are strings.

Output:

```
>>> s
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
```